# How to get on ggraph the same plot as with RCy3 (Cytoscape)

Tags: layout, coordinates, nodes, cytoscape, ggraph

I can get thanks to the function RCy3::getNodePosition() x and y coordinates from a graph plot drawn with RCy3 on Cytoscape. Then, I can use ggraph with layout based on the dataframe prepared from coordinates. I have got a graph but with a deeply different structure from the previous one. What could explain this difference?

**Consider the following example coming from:**
http://cytoscape.org/RCy3/articles/Network-functions-and-visualization.html

'''

```
library(RCy3)
library(ggraph)
```

'''

'''

```
lesmis <- system.file("extdata","lesmis.txt", package="RCy3")
dataSet <- read.table(lesmis, header = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

'''

Create a graph. Use simplify to ensure that there are no duplicated edges or self loops

'''

```
gD <- igraph::simplify(igraph::graph.data.frame(dataSet, directed=FALSE))
```

'''

Verify the number of nodes (77) and edges (254):

'''

```
igraph::vcount(gD)
igraph::ecount(gD)
```

'''

**create the graph gD on Cytoscape**
'''

```
createNetworkFromIgraph(gD,new.title='Les Miserables')
```

'''

create a graph using ggraph

'''

```
ggraph(gD, layout = 'kk') + 
  geom_edge_link(color = "orange", width=0.7) +
  geom_node_point(size=5, color="gray50")+
  geom_node_text(aes(label = vlabels_1), size=2, color="gray50", repel=T) +
  theme_void()
```

'''

It is qualitatively the same graph obtained by ggraph as on Cytoscape by using RCy3::createNetworkFromIgraph()

Then, we can get coordinates from graph on Cytoscape as following:

'''

```
mygraph_Miserables <- createIgraphFromNetwork()
mylayout_Miserables <- getNodePosition()

mylayout_Miserables$x_location <- as.numeric(as.character(mylayout_Miserables$x_location))

mylayout_Miserables$y_location <- as.numeric(as.character(mylayout_Miserables$y_location))

colnames(mylayout_Miserables) <- c('x','y')

vlabels_1 <- get.vertex.attribute(gD, "name")
color_labels_1 <- getNodeColor(vlabels_1)

ggraph(mygraph_Miserables, layout = mylayout_Miserables) + 
  geom_edge_link(color = "orange", width=0.7) +
  geom_node_point(size=5, color="gray50") +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = vlabels_1), size=2, color="gray50", repel=T) +
  theme_void()
```

'''

This new graph obtained by ggraph using layout = mylayout_Miserables doesn't provide the same structure of the graph provide directly by ggraph or by RCy3.
How can we explain that?

Alain Paris

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.